# How to prevent users from copying text from RichTextBox in a C# application?

Tags: c#, copy, richtextbox

Is it somehow possible to prevent end users from copying text from `RichTextBox` in a C# application? Maybe something like adding a transparent panel above the `RichTextBox`?

Comment: please describe your goal more clearly... and also how secure this needs to be ? which depends on the capabilities of the user you want to defend against...

Comment: @Yahia Given the goal he _thinks_ he has, he is describing it pretty clearly. What you mean is that he should not be asking this question, but rather a different one. But if he changes his question, then all answers so far will be invalid. So, I do not think that we should be encouraging people to change questions. Perhaps we should be telling them to ask different ones.

Comment: Same way as for TextBox: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113722/how-to-disable-copy-paste-and-delete-features-on-a-textbox-using-c-sharp

Comment: You could disable the textbox.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/345506

> Re: Disable copy and paste control for Richtextbox control Two steps
>   to be followed to disable the Copy-Paste feature in a textbox,
>
> 1) To stop right click copy/paste, disable the default menu and
>   associate the textbox with an empty context menu that has no menu
>   items.
>
> 2) To stop the shortcut keys you'll need to override the ProcessCmdKey
>   method:
>
> C# Syntax (Toggle Plain Text)

```
private const Keys CopyKey = Keys.Control | Keys.C;
private const Keys PasteKey = Keys.Control | Keys.V;

protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) { 
    if((keyData == CopyKey) || (keyData == PasteKey)){
        return true;
    } else {
      return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to subclass the rich edit box control, override the WM_COPY message, and do nothing when you receive it. (Do not delegate to DefWindowProc.)

You will also have to do the same for WM_CUT.

And still anyone will be able to get the text using some utility like Spy++.

Comment: This would be the most complete solution

Answer (score 1):

One way to doing it is make access to clipbord object and than you can manitpulate content of clipbord.

method for clearing clipbord is : [Clipboard.Clear Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.clear.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this (I think):

```
//Stick this in the KeyDown event of your RichtextBox
    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.C) {
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
```

Comment: This is not correct because there are many ways to perform a copy operation, and Ctrl+C is just one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Another -very elegant- working option (which also prevents context-menu actions).

The XAML:

```
<RichTextBox CommandManager.PreviewExecuted="richTextBox_PreviewExecuted"/>
```

The code-behind:

```
private void richTextBox_PreviewExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Command == ApplicationCommands.Copy ||
        e.Command == ApplicationCommands.Cut  ||
        e.Command == ApplicationCommands.Paste)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

(Source: https://programmingistheway.wordpress.com/2016/09/07/disable-wpf-textbox-cut-copy-and-paste/)

Also, if it's of interest, you can "convert" the "Cut" command into a "Copy" one (in order to allow copying but aviod moficiation):

```
private void richTextBox_PreviewExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Command == ApplicationCommands.Paste)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    else if (e.Command == ApplicationCommands.Cut)
    {
        ApplicationCommands.Copy.Execute(e.Parameter, (IInputElement)sender);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```