# How to prevent richTextBox to paste images within it?

Tags: c#, bitmap, richtextbox

I am programming in c#. and I've a richTextBox on it.

At runtime, I insert some Bitmap images into richTextbox by coding.
But I want to prevent user that drag my inserted Images or paste some other images in richTextBox.

How can I implement that?

thanks in advance!

Comment: You can chane the richtextbox property to "readonly" but, you don't want to disable "writing/copy-paste features" for texts. Am I right?

Comment: You should add your answer as an answer to your question and accept it. It will add closure to it.

Comment: Please can you remove the answer from the question and add it as a new answer, then you can accept it. This will improve the usefulness of the question for other visitors

Comment: This doesn't look a duplicate to me. TheJonz answered something which I could use, not found in the "already answered" link. I guess both questions are a bit fuzzy in that the don't tell what should be done with casual text data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this code and it works perfectly:

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        //if ((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) == Keys.Control && (e.KeyChar == 'V' || e.KeyChar == 'v'))
        if (((int)e.KeyChar) == 22)
        {
            if(hasImage(Clipboard.GetDataObject()));
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                richTextBox1.Undo();
                MessageBox.Show("can't paste image here!!");
            }


        }
    }

    private Boolean hasImage(object obj)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox richTextBox = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
        Object data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(data);
        richTextBox.Paste();
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(data);
        int offset = richTextBox.Rtf.IndexOf(@"\f0\fs17") + 8; // offset = 118;
        int len = richTextBox.Rtf.LastIndexOf(@"\par") - offset;
        return richTextBox.Rtf.Substring(offset, len).Trim().Contains(@"{\pict\");
    }
```

And disabled dragdrop in richTextBox.
thanks

Comment: Why did you use `offset` and `len`? Why not using a simple
`richTextBox.Rtf.Contains(@"{\pict\")` ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just allow plain text pasted from the clipboard then you can do the following... (warning this replaces the clipboard with plain text)

```
private void textbox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.V)
    {
        Clipboard.SetText((string)Clipboard.GetData("Text"), TextDataFormat.Text);
    }
}
```

By doing this your RichTextBox will still allow undo and will work when it has some text highlight (neither one is supported in the answer from Zarathos located here: [How to Make RichTextBox Text Only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321385/how-to-make-richtextbox-text-only))

Comment: This code was very useful to past the text of a OneNote box to a RTF control in pure text mode. Default is image.

Comment: You can still paste images with shift+insert using this.

Comment: Better use `DataFormats.Text` instead of `"Text"`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the [AllowDrop Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.allowdrop.aspx) to False to disable dropping. As far as preventing your content from being copy and pasted. You can do something like this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113722/how-to-disable-copy-paste-and-delete-features-on-a-textbox-using-c-sharp) suggests by using [ShortcutsEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.shortcutsenabled.aspx) to disable Shortcuts or just preventing pasting by making the control [ReadOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.readonly.aspx)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply.updated question with a solution. I setted AllowDrop Property to false and it works.but about paste, I want to user allowed to paste texts. however I found out the solution. thanks.