# Override WM_PASTE in comboBox?

Tags: vb.net

I am asking someone here to add in a override to disable right clicking the control, and if that is not possible, would it be possible to just disable pasting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See p.campbell's answer to [how to disable copy, Paste and delete features on a textbox using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113722/how-to-disable-copy-paste-and-delete-features-on-a-textbox-using-c-sharp)

```
public CueComboBox(): base()
{
    //disable right click menu
    ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
}

private const Keys PasteKeys = Keys.Control | Keys.V;

protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == PasteKeys)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```

Comment: It still lets me paste...THIS DOES NOT WORK!