# Disable paste on a textbox via keypress

Tags: c#, keypress

I've assigned the following method to all of my

```
    private void textBox18_KeyPress_1(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        char a = Convert.ToChar(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator);


        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) &&
          (e.KeyChar != a))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        // only allow one decimal point 
        if ((e.KeyChar == a) && ((sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf(a) > -1))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }


    }
```

It basically allows one decimal separator (of any kind), and allows only numbers.
I'd rather disable "paste" as well on this method. Is this possible?

I know some users might redirect me here

[how to disable copy, Paste and delete features on a textbox using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113722/how-to-disable-copy-paste-and-delete-features-on-a-textbox-using-c-sharp)

But my code doesn't recognize `e.Control` and `e.KeyCode`. Even when I add `using Windows.Forms` at the form beginning. And even then, I wouldn't know if those solutions would work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those properties aren't available in the [`KeyPress` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The KeyPress event is not raised by non-character keys other than space and backspace; however, the non-character keys do raise the KeyDown and KeyUp events.

Subscribe to the `KeyDown` event, where you have access to any modifier keys (control, alt, shift) the user happens to be pressing.

```
 private void textBox18_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
     if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.V)
     {
         // cancel the "paste" function
         e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
     }
 }
```