# how to intercept winform textbox selection right click copy

Tags: winforms, textbox, copy, intercept

I need to transform the copied selection in a winform textbox before copying to clipboard. I have the ctrl-c done, but the right click copy would seem to require overriding WinProc,and the link in an example in [how to disable copy, Paste and delete features on a textbox using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113722/how-to-disable-copy-paste-and-delete-features-on-a-textbox-using-c-sharp) for WM_PASTE is no longer is valid. I would add failure may be a feature, because Ctrl-c could be transformed and right click copy could be the literal, both of which I need to do. I had hoped to radio button a state for a transformed or literal selection for choosing behavior.

Comment: It's not clear what is not working. Of course, if you need to *intercept* a Copy operation, `WM_PASTE` won't do much, you need to handle the `WM_COPY` message.

Answer (score 0):

My question was based on reading that the only way to do this was to handle a WM_COPY, but the better solution would be to implement a context menu strip for each text box as needed.
The right click context would then be handled by event handlers.