# C# + USB Barcode Reader

Tags: c#, barcode

How can i read **barcode text** in background in my C# app? I googled but its of no use. And other resources on stackoverflow are not close to what i need. I want to read barcode in background. And i want to know if the data is coming from barcode or key board. If the data comes from the barcode then it mustnot be displayed on textbox even though the textbox is highlighted. I got similar code for stackoverflow but if there is presence of textbox in the window then the textbox will contain barcode data; which i dont want.
Link : [get barcode reader value form background monitoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850050/get-barcode-reader-value-form-background-monitoring)

```
    DateTime _lastKeystroke = new DateTime(0);
    List<char> _barcode = new List<char>(10);

    private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        // check timing (keystrokes within 100 ms)
        TimeSpan elapsed = (DateTime.Now - _lastKeystroke);
        if (elapsed.TotalMilliseconds > 100)
            _barcode.Clear();

        // record keystroke & timestamp
        _barcode.Add(e.KeyChar);
        _lastKeystroke = DateTime.Now;

        // process barcode
        if (e.KeyChar == 13 && _barcode.Count > 0) {
            string msg = new String(_barcode.ToArray());
            MessageBox.Show(msg);
            _barcode.Clear();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most barcode scanners simply act as keyboard inputs and a quick / easy work around is to place a textbox "Out of sight". An example would be something like this:

```
// Pseudo code (could be Web, Windows etc)
public void Form1_Load()
{
    txtBarcodeScanner.Top = -10000;
    txtBarcodeScanner.Left = -10000;
    txtBarcodeScanner.Width = 10;
    txtBarcodeScanner.Height = 10;
    txtBarcodeScanner.Focus();
}
```

That way the input can be captured by `txtBarcodeScanner` but will not be visible and the barcode will not seen being captured but will fire `KeyDown` etc.

Comment: And what if i have multiple textbox in my application. I need to record the barcode data as well as textbox data in the same window. You may consider my application to be like a POS.

Comment: In that instance you normally have a timer that says if no user activity (i.e. typing) in x seconds then force focus back to the barcode text box or have a button that the operator clicks called **Scan** that pops up a form saying "Please scan now..." that contains the hidden text box. It depends on user experience you are after of course.

Comment: @Belogix why not just set [Control.Visible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visible.aspx) for the WinForm Textbox instead of moving it? That way you can have a property bound to your Textbox visibility.

Comment: @Bob because I believe if you make it not visible then you cannot set focus on it and record input, hence the hack to move it out of the way.

Answer (score 2):

Barcode device like keyboard.

1 When entering the barcode, press f12

2 The enter was pressed after inserting the barcode

```
private void textbox_Keydown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if(e.KeyCode == Keys.F12){
    Textbox.Focus();
   }
   if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter){
     /// after enter barcode
     /// save 
   }

}
```

Comment: I doubt it makes sense to handle the F12 and Enter keys in the same event handler - the F12 behavior is for all focusable controls *except* the barcode input box, the Enter behavior is only for the barcode input box.

Comment: This has been successfully tested
 - Before entering the barcode
 - pressed f12
 - After entering the barcode
 - pressed enter

Answer (score 0):

check user manual  that came with the scanner box.!!

[image: sunlox-xl-9610-usermanual]

does your barcode scanner supports  interfaceType: "usb virtual com port" ?

**if yes:**
you can do it using **serialport()** class

**1)** put your scanner into  **"usb virtual com port"** by scanning that barcode.
it will popup in the device manager.

**2)** get your baudrate info from device manager

- device manager ->

  - com lpt ports ->

    - usb serial ch341a (com6)

  -> (dobule click) -> "goto tab connection point settings"
  there is your baudrate parity etc. info ( write that info to connect port)

**3)** use this example to do the c# coding. [serialport to read data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16215767/3137362)

done!.