# I Can't use Barcode reader in the price checker device

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0, motorola

Hi every one i try to make an application for price checking merchandise and I am 
using this device

Name : Motorola 
Type : Symbol HOLTSVILLE N.Y. 11742
P/N  : MK500

I create a smart device application with visual studio 2005 (.Net 2.0) 
and my code is

```
private Symbol.Barcode.Reader MyReader = null;
private Symbol.Barcode.ReaderData MyReaderData = null; 

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyReader = new Symbol.Barcode.Reader();
    MyReaderData =
    new Symbol.Barcode.ReaderData(Symbol.Barcode.ReaderDataTypes.Text,
    Symbol.Barcode.ReaderDataLengths.DefaultText);
    MyReader.ReadNotify += new EventHandler(MyReader_ReadNotify);
    MyReader.Actions.Enable();
    MyReader.Actions.Read(MyReaderData);
    return; 
}

private void Form1_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    MyReader.Actions.Flush();
    MyReader.Actions.Disable();
    MyReader.Dispose();
    MyReaderData.Dispose();
    return; 
}

private void MyReader_ReadNotify(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(MyReaderData.Text, "HelloScan");
    MyReader.Actions.Read(MyReaderData);
    return;
}
```

But when i start deploying my application the Barcode reader not worked 
I don't know why!

every thing is okay
and the code and references all working good 
and there are other demo application already installed in the device and this one working smoothly so the device is okay too 
I don't know what can i do ?

Please any one can help me

Comment: I think you should have a TextBox in your form for the barcode reader.  When it detects a barcode, will write it in the texbox. (or even in a notepad!)

Answer (score 0):

the comment is correct, the application should have a textbox focused before making a read. The one from motorola sdk barcode sample1 file has a readnotify function:

```
public void SymbolReader_ReadNotify(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Symbol.Barcode.ReaderData TheReaderData = Scanner.SymbolReader.GetNextReaderData();
                if (TheReaderData.Result == Symbol.Results.SUCCESS && (txtBarcode.Focused == true))
                {
                    if (txtBarcode.Focused == true)
                    {
                        txtBarcode.Text = TheReaderData.Text.ToString();
                       Scanner.SymbolReader.Actions.Read(Scanner.SymbolReaderData);
                        return;
                    }
                }
                Scanner.SymbolReader.Actions.Read(Scanner.SymbolReaderData);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Barcode reader works like a keyboard. So you can listen for the keydown event in the desired window or any other control like textbox. And remember that the last keystroke that barcode sends is the return key. So you can distinguish between keyboard and barcode.

[C# + USB Barcode Reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17475210/c-sharp-usb-barcode-reader)

Hope that helps