# How to specify which writing object (keyboard/barcode scanner) can be used to write in textbox using C#?

Tags: c#, barcode, barcode-scanner

my question is: How can I set which input "object" will be enabled for entering text into a textbox? My case is: I'm making a program where I need to use barcode scanner, and in one form in my program I want to constraint the user so he can only write down using barcode scanner. Any ideas how to implement that?

I can see both of them from device manager (1. one is barcode scanner):
[image]

Comment: Maybe you could constrain the text to a valid barcode entry using something like a RegEx - such that if they attempt to enter text which isn't a barcode it automatically clears it.

Comment: @ChrisNevill already did that, but its not enough, because someone can remember his barcode (somehow) and enter it manually, I even hidden characters but I wanna make sure for every case.

Comment: It seems to me that you will have to go real low-level Windows API, to detect the specific device, and maybe even read the message directly from it. I don't know if it's worth the effort. Maybe you should consider some other safety measure.

Comment: Maybe see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850050/get-barcode-reader-value-form-background-monitoring

and remove the textbox?

Comment: @ChrisNevill good post, I'll think about it, in the end everything depends on what will be easier to do, your solution or some solution that someone else posts.

Answer (score 0):

A barcode scanner uses the keyboard interface of the computer: i.e. from the point of view of your textbox, it is just another keyboard.

If you want to force your user to use the barcode scanner instead of the "normal" keyboard, you have to somehow disable the normal keyboard in that situation. I do not know how to do that.

Comment: I understand that part and I even know how are they called from device manager, I edited my question, check it out