# Storing KeyPress input as a string

Tags: c#, keypress

I am scanning in a value from a barcode to a form, but it is not being entered into a textbox.  I would like to "build" a string from the values returned by KeyPress so that I can parse the barcode later.  I'm not sure how to set up a loop to capture all the characters from the barcode.

```
private string input;
private void MESMenu_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    input += e.KeyChar;
    MessageBox.Show(input);
}
```

Comment: I have solved it...using this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850050/get-barcode-reader-value-form-background-monitoring

Answer (score 0):

Key Press looks like a event. One the one hand there is a loop - the Event Queue. On the other hand, there is no loop you can use directly (as you get no counting variable).

There are workarounds but they all have the same problem: You need to figure out when one barcode is "done" and can be processed. And thus the next one can begin. Or when the input of a barcode failed (propably due to some number not being readable) and thus should be repeated.

Aside from that, you are on the right track: You need a Variable outside of the Event that you append to. This can be a string, a List, List (a lot of single Character strings) or a Stringbuilder.

String is often good enough for short cases. If you do a lot of assignments, there is a bit of overhead in string connaction. It comes from the Inmubtability of the string and the fact that there is features like string interning to save memory. Just to get around those optimisations/issues, StringBuilder was added.

One thing you should avoid is using any GUI Element as teh outside variable. Writing the GUI causes considerable overhead. Not a issue if you do it once per user triggered event. But from any kind of loop the effects can be massive:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace UIWriteOverhead
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        int[] getNumbers(int upperLimit)
        {
            int[] ReturnValue = new int[upperLimit];

            for (int i = 0; i < ReturnValue.Length; i++)
                ReturnValue[i] = i;

            return ReturnValue;
        }

        void printWithBuffer(int[] Values)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "";
            string buffer = "";

            foreach (int Number in Values)
                buffer += Number.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
            textBox1.Text = buffer;
        }

        void printDirectly(int[] Values){
            textBox1.Text = "";

            foreach (int Number in Values)
                textBox1.Text += Number.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
        }

        private void btnPrintBuffer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Generating Numbers");
            int[] temp = getNumbers(10000);
            MessageBox.Show("Printing with buffer");
            printWithBuffer(temp);
            MessageBox.Show("Printing done");
        }

        private void btnPrintDirect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Generating Numbers");
            int[] temp = getNumbers(1000);
            MessageBox.Show("Printing directly");
            printDirectly(temp);
            MessageBox.Show("Printing done");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just found this thread...of course I searched forever before I made this thread, and find this right after!   It isn't working quite yet but I feel like I am getting there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850050/get-barcode-reader-value-form-background-monitoring