# Barcode scanning from keyboard wedge scanner

Tags: c#, winforms, barcode-scanner

I am making a software which create entry of products and generate barcode for that product then it is placed on store when that product exist from store i need to scan that barcode to set the status of product.

it is on same win forms. The main problem was when cursor is set on any text box it does not work properly.

which method i have to apply so that i can distinguish the scanner and keyboard input.

please help. it is  c# winform application.

Comment: Which brand/type is the scanner?

Comment: Barcode scanner is honeywell 
model MS5145 LS USB

Comment: I suggest u to take a look at this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn792060(v=winembedded.81).aspx

Comment: Thank you. 
but i also have to take care that client can change scanner any time 
at that situation i did not want to change the code for that particular scanner

Comment: Just detect when the scanner is disconnected?

Comment: I don't think this is enough to constitute an answer, but when I had a similar issue (needing to do something globally in response to a barcode scanner that was essentially just a keyboard input) I used a global keypress handler and considered a series of inputs to be a barcode if they were entered at a very high speed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Check if User input is from Barcode Scanner or Keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088374/how-to-check-if-user-input-is-from-barcode-scanner-or-keyboard)